# Isotope is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery-isotope

In the https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3.0.6/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js isotope package, there is an error occurred `Uncaught ReferenceError: Isotope is not defined`

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing / (at isotope.pkgd.min.js:12:543)
```

This gives error at this line :

```
var i=h(t).split(" "),o=i[0],n=o.match(/^\[(.+)\]$/),s=n&&n[1],r=e(s,o),a=d.sortDataParsers[i[1]];
```

And at view source of the js page at website it shows below result to me :

```
var i=h(t).split(" "),o=i[0],n=o.match(/^\[(.+)\àã™êU��àã™êU������������������°7êU����������0_˜êU��Hä™êU�����������ä™êU��u�������ä™êU����������
```

What's the meaning of this?

I tried so many things but nothing worked...

How can I fix this issue...

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'at compling time' but it lLooks like your compiler hasn't loaded the js package correctly - you're just getting loads of invalid ASCII characteers

Comment: Here compiler means at view source page

Comment: OK, so the file isn't loading correctly. i suggest copying it to your own server and loading it from there, rather than directly from unpkg.com. You can then check more easily if (and where) the corruption is happening

Comment: I do it but till then also then same issue occurs every time

Comment: at the CDN level everything works fine but when I download that file to my server and link it and see the view page source of that js file then this error occurs...

Comment: you are downloading 3.0.6 which isn't mentioned on the GitHub page for Isotope. Why not try the standard release version [link] (https://isotope.metafizzy.co/#cdn) - maybe the non-min version would help isolate the problem.